# Finding a zero crossing in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I am trying create an algorithm for finding the zero crossing (check that the signs of all the entries around the entry of interest are not the same) in a two dimensional matrix, as part of implementing the Laplacian of Gaussian edge detection filter for a class, but I feel like I'm fighting against Numpy instead of working with it.

```
import numpy as np

range_inc = lambda start, end: range(start, end+1)

# Find the zero crossing in the l_o_g image
# Done in the most naive way possible
def z_c_test(l_o_g_image):
    print(l_o_g_image)
    z_c_image = np.zeros(l_o_g_image.shape)
    for i in range(1, l_o_g_image.shape[0] - 1):
        for j in range(1, l_o_g_image.shape[1] - 1):
            neg_count = 0
            pos_count = 0
            for a in range_inc(-1, 1):
                for b in range_inc(-1, 1):
                    if a != 0 and b != 0:
                        print("a ", a, " b ", b)
                        if l_o_g_image[i + a, j + b] < 0:
                            neg_count += 1
                            print("neg")
                        elif l_o_g_image[i + a, j + b] > 0:
                            pos_count += 1
                            print("pos")
                        else:
                            print("zero")

            # If all the signs around the pixel are the same
            # and they're not all zero
            # then it's not a zero crossing and an edge. 
            # Otherwise, copy it to the edge map.
            z_c = ((neg_count > 0) and (pos_count > 0))

            if z_c:
                print("True for", i, ",", j)
                print("pos ", pos_count, " neg ", neg_count)
                z_c_image[i, j] = 1

    return z_c_image
```

Here is the test cases it should pass:

```
test1 = np.array([[0,0,1], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]])
test2 = np.array([[0,0,1], [0,0,0], [0,0,-1]])
test3 = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,0,-1], [0,0,0]])
test4 = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]])
true_result = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,0]])
false_result = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]])

real_result1 = z_c_test(test1)
real_result2 = z_c_test(test2)
real_result3 = z_c_test(test3)
real_result4 = z_c_test(test4)

assert(np.array_equal(real_result1, false_result))
assert(np.array_equal(real_result2, true_result))
assert(np.array_equal(real_result3, false_result))
assert(np.array_equal(real_result4, false_result))
```

How do I vectorize checking a property in a matrix range? Is there a quick way of accessing all of the entries adjacent to an entry in a matrix?

Comment: adjacent meaning N,S,W,E or the 8 (or just 3) around the checked? currently it looks like the NSWE solution, but just to make sure.

Comment: It's supposed to be the 8.

Comment: @Vogel612 As shown in the unit tests and with my very awkward iteration using `a` and `b`.

Comment: you might want to have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20200199/1803692)

Comment: @Vogel612 I read in that answer that accessing adjacent cells should not be optimized. Was there anything else that I missed? I think that may be relevant for half of my problem, but for the other half where I'm iterating through each cell of the matrix, I think my question still stands.

Comment: it was only planned to give some help on the half of the problem..

Comment: You can try to either express this operation as a convolution, which I am not sure if your check can be expressed as. Otherwise, the function [scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) with `size` set to 3 should leave you with only writing a short function doing the check on the vector of neighborhood elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's concise method to get the coordinates of the zero-crossings that seems to work according to my tests :

```
def zcr(x, y):
    return x[numpy.diff(numpy.sign(y)) != 0]
```

Some simple test case :

```
>>> zcr(numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 3, 4, -4])
array([2, 4, 6])
```

This is 2d only, but I believe it is easy to adapt to more dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the neighbor coordinates without checking for (a != 0) or (b != 0) on every iteration would be to use a generator. Something like this:

```
def nborz():
    l = [(-1,-1), (-1,0), (-1,1), (0,-1), (0,1), (1,-1),(1,0),(1,1)]
    try:
        while True:
           yield l.pop(0)
    except StopIteration:
        return None
....

for i in range(1,l_o_g_image.shape[0]-1):
    for j in range(1,l_o_g_image.shape[1]-1):
        neg_count = 0
        pos_count = 0
        nbrgen = nborz()
        for (a,b) in nbrgen:
            print "a " + str(a) + " b " + str(b)
            if(l_o_g_image[i+a,j+b] < 0):
                neg_count += 1
                print "neg"
            elif(l_o_g_image[i+a,j+b] > 0):
                pos_count += 1
                print "pos"
            else:
                print "zero"
```

Comment: Would that actually be faster?

Comment: I would think it might, 1) because it avoids a comparison on every iteration of the inner loops, and 2) because it avoids computation of the index values for the inner loops (counting -1, 0, 1 twice in a nested fashion). However, I have not actually tried it so I don't know for sure.